# Looping over files in subfolders matching a pattern in Windows CMD prompt

Tags: for-loop, cmd

I am trying to find all files matching the wildcard `*\dev\*\*\*\Results_local.xml` in a cmd script, but I failed. I tried:

```
for %%f in (*\dev\*\*\*\Results_local.xml) do (
echo %%f
)
```

but it doesn't return any results. What should I do instead?

Comment: You cannot use * as a wildcard for directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dir /s/b /a-d Results_local.xml |findstr /i /b /r ".*\\dev\\.*\\.*\\.*\\"
```

should give you a results list.

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in (
 'dir /s/b /a-d Results_local.xml ^|findstr /i /b /r ".*\\dev\\.*\\.*\\.*\\"'
) do echo %%f
```

should apply the results to %%f one-by-one.